# Dataframe reshaping for tensorflow training

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow

I'm trying to get some data ready for training in a GAN model. This data is around 37k faces of resolution 28x28 with 3 channels each. At the moment, this data is in a Dataframe object and I would expect the shape of this data to be (37k, 28, 28, 3), but the shape turns out to be (37k,). Is there a way I can reshape this data to conform to this data to the proper shape?

Comment: With the sizes you described, it doesn't look like your object merely has the wrong shape; you seem to have the wrong number of elements. Or, perhaps each of the 37k objects is a 28 x 28 x 3 array. Could you check the shape of one of the 37k objects?

Comment: Sorry I should have elaborated more. Yeah each element shape is (28,28,3).

Comment: Gotcha. I think that you can get what you want using [stack](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/stack) on the whole array

Comment: Thankyou! that worked!

Comment: Glad to help. Putting my comment as an answer to get this question off the unanswered queue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do can be implemented using the [stack function](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/stack).